# Array isn't following edges of curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I converted my rectangle into a curve so that the array can follow the path, but as you can see in the picture it's trying to smooth the edges. I already applied scale, location and rotation for the curve and the array, but it didn't solve the problem. I don't have any unapplied modifiers on my curve.

File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c2ogiodGyhzVrWPXdxHMtTJrR9jsoBaK

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your curve **Preview resolution is low**,
[image]

So, in the curve-properties, increase the curve **Preview resolution**

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you, first time using the curve modifier.

Comment: It's odd that a poly-curve rectangle is sampled for length in the same sort of way as a Bezier? If you turn the resolution to 1, you can see where the samples are taken, and where the (approximation of position at length x) is linearly interpolated. The approximations don't wind up at the corners. I can't help thinking a little bit of rewriting could avoid this, without hurting anything else.